# RAM gets used up in shell script and I don't understand why

Tags: bash

I have a large 'csv' file (about 4.5GB) and I need to remove some of the columns since I don't need them. I'm a complete beginner when it comes to bash, so I'm probably doing something fundamentally wrong, but my script uses up all the RAM on my computer until it becomes unusable.

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS="," read -r col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10 
do
   if [[ "$col6" = '0'  ]]
   then 
       continue 
   else
       echo "$col1, $col2, $col6,"$'\r' >> cleaned.csv
   fi 
done < data.csv
```

I'm not really sure why the RAM grows here, since I don't see where I'm saving something into memory that could become 10+GB large... Also, if I change the above code to

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS="," read -r col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10 
do
   echo "$col1, $col2, $col6,"$'\r' >> cleaned.csv
done < data.csv
```

Everything works out fine...

---

**EDIT:**
Example of the 'csv'-file:

```
username,id,my_watched_episodes,my_start_date,my_finish_date,my_score,my_status,my_rewatching,my_rewatching_ep,my_last_updated,my_tags
karthiga,21,586,0000-00-00,0000-00-00,9,1,,0,1362307973,
karthiga,59,26,0000-00-00,0000-00-00,7,2,,0,1362923691,
karthiga,74,26,0000-00-00,0000-00-00,7,2,,0,1367081015,
karthiga,120,26,0000-00-00,0000-00-00,7,2,,0,1362308037,
karthiga,178,26,0000-00-00,0000-00-00,7,2,0,0,1364399953,
karthiga,210,161,0000-00-00,0000-00-00,7,2,,0,1362923826,
karthiga,232,70,0000-00-00,0000-00-00,6,2,,0,1362849882,
karthiga,233,78,0000-00-00,0000-00-00,6,2,,0,1362893384,
karthiga,249,167,0000-00-00,0000-00-00,8,2,,0,1363709086,
karthiga,269,366,0000-00-00,0000-00-00,10,2,,0,1362303563,
```

Comment: What happens if you change the conditional test to `if [[ "$col6' == "0" ]]` ?

Comment: @fpmurphy been running for a good 3 mins and ram seems stable at normal level, so the change seems to have solved the problem... Could you maybe elaborate shortly on what is happening here?

Comment: Difficult to tell, as that fix appears to have unbalanced quotes. Does your input file also have \r line endings? Bash would probably read the whole file into col10 in that case (treating it as one line), which would certainly eat the memory.

Comment: @Sito  Typo in my suggestion. Should be `if [[ "$col6" == "0" ]]`

Comment: @fpmurphy I didn't even notice the typo... Put your second suggestion in and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be treating the CSV such that no field contains a comma. Assuming that's acceptable for this file you could use `awk` directly

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } !$6 { print $1, $2, $6 }' data.csv > cleaned.csv
```

If you really do need `\r` as your line terminator (rather than `\n`) use this instead

```
awk -F, '!$6 { printf "%s,%s,%s\r", $1, $2, $6 }' data.csv > cleaned.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
if [[ "$col6" = '0' ]]
```

to

```
if [[ "$col6" == "0" ]]
```

to eliminate the memory issue.

Comment: But in Bash `==` and `=` are equivalent. I'm still puzzled as to why this solves the problem and why the problem arised in the first place.

Comment: @Quasímodo Even though the problem is solved, I'd still love to know what happend as well..